# How to fix java.sql.SQLException: Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'user'@'host' has a password in the old format; (...)?

Tags: java, mysql, upgrade, password-encryption

After upgrading MySQL 5.1 to 5.6, trying to start JBoss failed with this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
  Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'user'@'localhost' 
  has a password in the old format;  please change the password to the new format
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Trying to start which server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed by:

**1)** Update the value of the password hash of the 'user' user

`UPDATE mysql.user set password = PASSWORD('my password text') where user= 'user';`

**2)** Stop 'mysql' server

`/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

**3)** Set the flag `old_passwords=1` on the `/etc/my.cnf` file

**4)** Start 'mysql' server

`/etc/init.d/mysql start`

See also documentation: [MySQL password hashing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to locate the `my.cnf` file, which should be at the following path:

```
MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf
```

Next find the line which says `old_passwords=0` and change it to `old_passwords=1`.  This will tell MySQL to use a password hashing algorithm compatible going all the way back to version 4.0, which covers your use case.

Now when you start your server, the password problem should go away.  If you want to upgrade your passwords to latest version, then you can use `SET PASSWORD` for each user *with the flag* `old_passwords=0`.

Please keep in mind that MySQL upgraded their password algorithm for security reasons, so you should not view setting `old_passwords=1` as a long term solution.

See [here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/upgrading-passwords-from-old_passwords-to-new-passwords) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the password for the JBOSS user to the same password it was before. The new version of MySQL will then hash with the new strong algorithm and it will start working again.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this was fixed by turning secure auth off.

Edit `/etc/my.cnf`

Add under the [mysqld] section:

```
old_passwords=1
secure-auth=false
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case the password user was incorrect.
Instead of like `dbname_userName` I just gave `userName`.
After rechecking the username, password etc I corrected them and run successfully.